# Spring-ws WCF WS client example

Tags: spring, wcf, spring-ws

Is there any example about how to write a WCF WS client using Spring-ws in order to consume a .Net WCF WS?

Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to __recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic__ for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The fact that the Web service is implemented in WCF shouldn't matter. You can use any of the many available Spring-WS tutorials to get started.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. My mistake was that I was entering a wrong SOAPAction